# Mongoose's loadClass() with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Mongoose accepts an [ES6 class](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/advanced_schemas.html#creating-from-es6-classes-using-loadclass) as the basis for a schema.

The example from that link:

```
class PersonClass {

  get fullName() {
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;    // compiler error
  }

}

PersonSchema.loadClass(PersonClass);
```

The schema's properties are not defined in the class, so the TypeScript compiler says:

> Property firstName does not exist on type PersonClass.

A hack is to use a dummy constructor:

```
constructor(readonly firstName: string, readonly lastName: string) { }
```

However that is hack, and harder to maintain.

Is there some other way to do this, without hacks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to use the `this IPerson` annotation:

```
get fullName(this IPerson) {
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
}
```

Where `IPerson` is the corresponding interface for that schema.

Comment: With my Typescript version 3.4.5 I have to use `this: IPerson` instead of `this IPerson`.