# Use es6 classes with mongoose in typescript with loadClass

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose, es6-class

I have this isue and I've searched the whole of Google without any answer. I am trying to use es6 classes with mongoose by loading the class (i.e schema.loadClass(class)), but typescript throw errors saying there are missing members in the class. Something like this:

```
//user.model.ts

import {Schema, model, Document} from "mongoose"
import User from "./user"

const schema = new Schema({
name:String,
age:Number, 
})

export interface IUser{
name:string;
age:number;
}

schema.loadClass(UserClass)
export const User = model<IUser>("User", schema)
```

```
//user.ts


export default class UserClass{
  intro():string{
return `my name is ${this.name} and I am ${this.age} years old`
}
}
```

though, this is an example, is there a way to fix this? You just saved a family by answering this question, thank you.

Comment: This an interesting one.  I can see some of the problems right away but I need to research the solutions.  Your `class UserClass` doesn't have any knowledge about the `IUser` interface, so it is going to complain when accessing `this.name` and `this.age` as those properties aren't defined on `UserClass`.  Potentially a `class` doesn't make sense here for that reason.

Comment: Looking at the examples https://mongoosejs.com/docs/advanced_schemas.html it's hard to see how it would work with typescript because we need to let typescript know about properties which are only available at run-time, while typescript runs at compile time when those properties aren't present.

Comment: Based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54724614/10431574  I think this works: https://tsplay.dev/nWPakw Let me know what specific errors you get if there are any.

Comment: It was complaining about the context of "this" being used differently because I've had a mothher class call ```Userclass.info()```. I had to silence the errors using //@ts-ignore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like we already have an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54724614/7372199).

Your implementation class `UserClass` should go like

```
export default class UserClass {
  intro(this: IUser): string {
    return `my name is ${this.name} and I am ${this.age} years old`;
  }
}
```

`UserClass` assumes `this` as its own object, unless you define it otherwise.

Furthermore, you may also modify `user.model.ts` like this

```
import { Schema, connection, Document } from "mongoose"
import User from "./user"

export interface IUser {
  name: string,
  age: number,
  intro(): string, // to get it via intellisense, user.intro()
}
type IntroDocument = IUser & Document;

const schema = new Schema<IntroDocument>({
  name: String,
  age: Number,
})

schema.loadClass(UserClass);
export const User = connection.model<IUser>("User", schema);
```

Edit: Unlike how the OP posted, note that, `model` needs to be imported from `connection` object(`mongoose v5.11.13`).